# Parsing Google Maps JSON with APEX

Tags: apex, api, json

I work for a small non-profit that helps young people from disadvantaged backgrounds get a start in STEM careers. We're looking to match participants with placements based on location parameters so I thought it would be useful to use Google distancematrix API to return journey times rather than linear distance.

I've built the https callout in my flow and can pass the relevant info and pull back a response. The problem is that the response is in JSON format which is fine when I'm just displaying it for a quick test but then I want to add data to the Applicant records.

I've tried JSON2Apex, I've tried chatGPT, I've tried unofficialSFs datamapper to get the information out. They all failed. I've failed.

When trying to pass a parameter from the flow to the code generated by chatGPT, it only allows me to access the 2xx.status parameter when I think I need the Rows parameter.

I need to be able pass the JSON and return the duration value (seconds) and text ("1 hr 35 mins")

its probably not the most efficient way as I know the distance matrix can take multiple addresses in each call but I'm currently looping through each applicant and calling the api with their address vs the placement address

I am not a coder, so I'm not clear what I need to do to fix this or if its possible.

the example JSON is:

```
{
  "destination_addresses": [
    "Lexington, MA, USA",
    "Concord, MA, USA"
  ],
  "origin_addresses": [
    "Boston, MA, USA",
    "Charlestown, Boston, MA, USA"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "33.3 km",
            "value": 33253
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "27 mins",
            "value": 1620
          },
          "duration_in_traffic": {
            "text": "34 mins",
            "value": 2019
          },
          "status": "OK"
        },
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "41.5 km",
            "value": 41491
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "33 mins",
            "value": 1981
          },
          "duration_in_traffic": {
            "text": "39 mins",
            "value": 2342
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "31.1 km",
            "value": 31100
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "26 mins",
            "value": 1543
          },
          "duration_in_traffic": {
            "text": "29 mins",
            "value": 1754
          },
          "status": "OK"
        },
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "39.3 km",
            "value": 39338
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "32 mins",
            "value": 1904
          },
          "duration_in_traffic": {
            "text": "35 mins",
            "value": 2077
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

and the example APEX is:

```
public class DistanceDurationCalculator {

    @InvocableMethod(
        label='Calculate Distance and Duration',
        description='Calculates distance and duration from Flow inputs'
    )
    public static List<Result> calculateDistanceAndDuration(List<FlowInput> flowInputs) {
        List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

        for (FlowInput flowInput : flowInputs) {
            for (FlowElement element : flowInput.elements) {
                String durationText = element.durationText;
                Integer durationValue = element.durationValue;
                String distanceText = element.distanceText;
                Integer distanceValue = element.distanceValue;

                Result result = new Result(durationText, durationValue, distanceText, distanceValue);
                results.add(result);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    public class FlowInput {
        public List<FlowElement> elements;
    }

    public class FlowElement {
        public String durationText;
        public Integer durationValue;
        public String distanceText;
        public Integer distanceValue;
    }

    public class Result {
        public String durationText;
        public Integer durationValue;
        public String distanceText;
        public Integer distanceValue;

        public Result(String durationText, Integer durationValue, String distanceText, Integer distanceValue) {
            this.durationText = durationText;
            this.durationValue = durationValue;
            this.distanceText = distanceText;
            this.distanceValue = distanceValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why "return the duration value (seconds) and text ("1 hr 35 mins")"? Don't you need the list of rows and elements? (Apologies, still haven't looked at the docs.)

Comment: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/category/geolocation might be a better place to start. Aside from the geolocation issue, look at [NPSP](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/explore-nonprofit-success-pack) - many nonprofits use that.

Answer (score 3):

I still have to have a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview). I don't fully understand the result that you present in your example JSON, but below is a first attempt at making the information gleaned from the JSON ready to be passed back to the Flow:

```apex
public with sharing class DistanceMatrixInfo {

    public virtual class Part {
        public String text;
        public Integer value;
    }

    public class distance extends Part {}
    public class duration extends Part {}
    public class duration_in_traffic extends Part {}

    public class Element {
        public distance distance;
        public duration duration;
        public duration_in_traffic duration_in_traffic;
        public String status;
    }

    public class Row {
        public List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
    }

    private class Info {
        private List<String> destination_addresses = new List<String>();
        private List<String> origin_addresses = new List<String>();
        public List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();
        private String status;
    }

    private Info inf;

    public DistanceMatrixInfo(String jsonString) {
        inf = (Info)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Info.class);
    }

    public List<Row> getRows() {
        return inf.rows;
    }
}
```

Instantiate this class from your `DistanceDurationCalculator` by passing the JSON string to the constructor. Retrieve the rows by the method `getRows()`.

I have validated this with the following test class:

```apex
@IsTest
private with sharing class DistanceMatrixInfoTest {
    
    @IsTest
    private static void getResults() {
        String exampleJsonString = '{   "destination_addresses": [     "Lexington, MA, USA",     "Concord, MA, USA"   ],   "origin_addresses": [     "Boston, MA, USA",     "Charlestown, Boston, MA, USA"   ],   "rows": [     {       "elements": [         {           "distance": {             "text": "33.3 km",             "value": 33253           },           "duration": {             "text": "27 mins",             "value": 1620           },           "duration_in_traffic": {             "text": "34 mins",             "value": 2019           },           "status": "OK"         },         {           "distance": {             "text": "41.5 km",             "value": 41491           },           "duration": {             "text": "33 mins",             "value": 1981           },           "duration_in_traffic": {             "text": "39 mins",             "value": 2342           },           "status": "OK"         }       ]     },     {       "elements": [         {           "distance": {             "text": "31.1 km",             "value": 31100           },           "duration": {             "text": "26 mins",             "value": 1543           },           "duration_in_traffic": {             "text": "29 mins",             "value": 1754           },           "status": "OK"         },         {           "distance": {             "text": "39.3 km",             "value": 39338           },           "duration": {             "text": "32 mins",             "value": 1904           },           "duration_in_traffic": {             "text": "35 mins",             "value": 2077           },           "status": "OK"         }       ]     }   ],   "status": "OK" }';

        Test.startTest();
        DistanceMatrixInfo inf = new DistanceMatrixInfo(exampleJsonString);
        List<DistanceMatrixInfo.Row> rows = inf.getRows();
        Test.stopTest();

        Assert.areEqual('33.3 km', rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
        Assert.areEqual(33253, rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
        Assert.areEqual('27 mins', rows[0].elements[0].duration.text);
    }
}
```

### ... and after a look at the documentation

I understand that Google's "rows" represent "origin addresses", Google's "elements" "destination addresses". You are therefore likely to need a class that holds incoming and outgoing data together - something like this:

```apex
public class DistanceDurationCalculatorResult {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Distance')
    public Decimal distance;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Duration')
    public Decimal duration;

    @InvocableVariable(label='From')
    public String fromLocation;

    @InvocableVariable(label='To')
    public String toLocation;
}
```

I'm not quite sure I understand how the JSON response is supposed to get into your InvocableMethod. When the afore `DistanceMatrixInfo` is not improved, you will probably need something like the following (I'm adding dummy data to make the relationships clear):

```apex
// somehow incoming data...
List<String> originAddresses = new List<String>{
    'Boston, MA, USA', 'Charlestown, Boston, MA, USA'};
List<String> destinationAddresses = new List<String>{
    'Lexington, MA, USA', 'Concord, MA, USA'};
// e.g. data as the one you presented
String webServiceResponseBody = '...';

DistanceMatrixInfo info = new DistanceMatrixInfo(webServiceResponseBody);
List<DistanceMatrixInfo.Row> rows = info.getRows();

List<DistanceDurationCalculatorResult> results 
    = new List<DistanceDurationCalculatorResult>();
for(Integer i=0; i<rows.size(); i++) {
    for(Integer j=0; j<rows[0].elements.size(); rows[0].elements) {
        DistanceMatrixInfo.Element element = rows[i].elements[j];
        DistanceDurationCalculatorResult result 
            = new DistanceDurationCalculatorResult();
        result.fromLocation = originAddresses[i];
        result.toLocation = destinationAddresses[j];
        result.distance = element.distance.value;
        result.duration = element.duration.value;
        results.add(result);
    }
}
```

I haven't tried anything of this, so take it with a grain of salt. The bigger job wil be to utilize the result (which is likely to be a list of lists) in the Flow...

Comment: ...or you could just pop https://github.com/googlemaps/openapi-specification into Flow or External Services and voila!

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/use-external-services-with-a-flow